# Jprofiler Agent Install error Centos 7

Tags: java, linux, tomcat8, jprofiler

I am trying to Install Jprofiler agent of Centos 7 64 bit with Java 8 and Tomcat 8

root@ads [/opt/jprofiler9]# jpenable
    Connecting to org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start [23360] ...
    Please select the profiling mode:
    GUI mode (attach with JProfiler GUI) [1, Enter]
    Offline mode (use config file to set profiling settings) [2]
    1
    Please enter a profiling port
    [59687]
    8849

```html
ERROR: Attaching is not supported: Unable to open socket file: target process not responding or HotSpot VM not loaded
com.sun.tools.attach.AttachNotSupportedException: Unable to open socket file: target process not responding or HotSpot VM not loaded
 at sun.tools.attach.LinuxVirtualMachine.<init>(LinuxVirtualMachine.java:100)
 at sun.tools.attach.LinuxAttachProvider.attachVirtualMachine(LinuxAttachProvider.java:63)
 at com.sun.tools.attach.VirtualMachine.attach(VirtualMachine.java:195)
 at com.jprofiler.a.d.b(ejt:292)
 at com.jprofiler.a.d.a(ejt:279)
 at com.jprofiler.a.d.a(ejt:249)
 at com.jprofiler.cli.EnableApplication.a(ejt:132)
 at com.jprofiler.cli.EnableApplication.h(ejt:95)
 at com.jprofiler.cli.b.a(ejt:26)
 at com.jprofiler.cli.EnableApplication.main(ejt:272)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
 at com.exe4j.runtime.LauncherEngine.launch(LauncherEngine.java:65)
 at com.install4j.runtime.launcher.UnixLauncher.main(UnixLauncher.java:57)
```

Answer (score 0):

In that case you cannot use `jpenable`, but you have to use `jpintegrate` to modify the start script of the profiled application and add the `-agentpath` parameter that loads the profiling agent at startup.

Comment: I found the solution.
When I execute root@ads [/home]# sudo -u tomcat /opt/jprofiler9/bin/jpenable

Answer (score 0):

Are you using sudo to run jpenable ?
Dont use sudo to start jpenable as well as the java process.